# How to mute downlink voice call on android?

Tags: android, audio, call, core-audio, voice

I work with AOSP 4.4.2 build. We'd like to mute downlink voice call sound for a while. How can we that? We already test with AudioManager's setStreamMute, setStreamVolume, but it was not working on our projects.

Like a mute a camera shutter sounds, we now finding some solution on audio_policy.